# What is the proper way to recover after coworker reported an issue to HR

Tags: colleagues

One of my team mates reported to HR that he could not put up with the smell of hand cream I put on. HR set up a meeting to let me know about this complaint. People have had different reactions to the smell. But what shocked me was that we have been working as a team for long time, we organize team lunches, drinks after work, weekend lunches, hiking etc... and I have difficulty understanding why he could not talk with me directly, but escalated to HR instead. I am trying to keep my cool, but my confidence towards this team has been jeopardized.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Sounds like that's only the tip of the iceberg. Maybe this guy is holding a grudge against you for a reason you are not aware of. Completely understandable that you feel disturbed.

Comment: I would rather think a bright side that he is not.

Comment: The current climate for males is "guilty until proven otherwise", so I can understand the guy being careful with matters related to the personal hygiene of a female coworker (assuming the team mate in question is of male persuasion). It's not personal, but he probably likes to keep his job.

Comment: The problem now is things are a bit awkward between you and him. You thought all was fine and well and it seems like they're not. So the best way to deal with this is just to break the ice with him directly. There is no need to make a big deal about it. Just next time you see him around the office, behave like everything is exactly the same, be friendly and smile and say something like "I didn't realize that my hand lotion was a problem! I've changed it now and I hope this one is better. You're welcome to let me know if there's anything else that bothers you!"

Comment: Then go on as if nothing has happened. It's been addressed, no need to make a big deal. You've told him that he's welcome to talk to you directly next time. It's over and in the past.

Comment: @Stacey, Thanks for your great answer. I can say those words if I know which one got bothered among 4 guys sitting surrounding me.

Comment: @EmmaM Would it be awkward to say it to the group?

Comment: @Fildor  I try not to do it to my group. I found myself uncomfortable no matter who he would be if I dig out. So when HR talked with me, I said I would be open and happy if he comes to talk with me directly whenever he feels comfortable.

Comment: Did HR tell you who brought up the issue?  The whole point of raising it to HR is to let them handle it anonymously to try to minimize ill feelings within the team.   I'm not sure how I would approach this with a co-worker directly.  You should probably try to minimize cosmetics that have a strong order if you are in an open or semi-open set-up.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was busy writing it when the question was closed. I don't actually think it's that unclear of a question, "things are weird now, how do I fix that?"

Comment: I think saying it to the group is totally a viable strategy. You can make a blanket statement to everybody. The trick is to treat it like it's no big deal, address it lightheartdly and then put it behind you.

Comment: This Q might work better on IPS.

Comment: @Stacey I think your comment would make a good answer too.  And it has been re-opened.

Comment: There have been questions where people asked about what to do if their cube-mate stinks, wears overwhelming fragrances or eats excessively pungent food. Some people always answer with "go to HR/manager". Well, now we see what happens when the offended actor actually does that-- things DO get weird. Don't run to HR and especially not managers over stuff like this. It reflects _very_ badly on the complainer and creates unnecessary stress for everyone involved.

Comment: @Teego1967, I'm not sure I agree. From Emma's comment, it does seem like other people have had various reactions to her hand cream, so if the coworker knew about those other reactions and Emma still didn't stop using that hand cream, it's possible that he didn't think his opinion would have a direct impact on Emma's behavior. Also, I don't think switching hand cream may be enough. Emma, maybe you should consider switching hand cream and only putting it on after work at night and never in the morning (unless it's on the weekends).

Answer (score 15):

This isn't really an issue.

You had one co-worker who didn't feel confident enough to bring up this point with you in the normal face-to-face manner (as many of us would).

You can't assume that the rest of your co-workers share the same behaviour.

I suspect that when approached, HR asked why this person couldn't ask you directly; maybe this hint as sunk in for anything else this person might not like.

You might want to separately ask HR why this guy felt that he couldn't approach you directly.  This might point to an underlying issue or misunderstanding somewhere (perhaps he feels that complaining to a lady directly may be seen as being sexist).

Comment: I concur that it is non-issue, just use scentless hand cream. As for HR, well continue to be polite and respectful to your team mate. The level of conflict for a person to approach HR to resolve issues differs from person to person. In other words, some people like to make mountains out of small things. Don't take it personally.

Comment: Nevertheless, taking such a non-issue to *HR* takes it to a whole new level of douche-baggery. I somehow understand that this (the HR-part) *is* an issue for OP.

Comment: @Fildor Hence my last paragraph here.  Hopefully, the HR department has realised that this is an inter-personal issue rather than something to do with the workplace.

Comment: +1 I commented before the edit. *Maybe* it would be worth a direct approach to the co-worker on why he didn't just ask. Making sure it's a non-issue for her (in the sense that asking wouldn't have been a big issue) may be able to "clear the smoke" somehow?

Comment: Thanks for all your advise. I try to be cool. But I kind of lost trust toward co-worker who I work with, smile at everyday.

Comment: @EmmaM I can understand this.  This is why it might be an idea to ask if HR know the reason why he couldn't raise this concern to you personally.  There might well be a perfectly innocent reason.

Comment: *This isn't really an issue.* Citation Needed

Comment: Litigative times incentivise formality. Maybe the person is a sniper who likes to shoot without being seen; or else, they go formal to avoid getting in trouble. It's not good for atmosphere, but fear of litigation isn't good for atmosphere either. Ignore and go on your way; it is ok to be a faint tad cooler to your colleagues as response (clearly an asymmetry in trust between you and them was already present), but I wouldn't bring it up explicitly; nothing to gain, and stirring up more trouble. Ignore that you suffered a mild form of losing face, just change your hand lotion and let go.

Comment: +1 for 'ask HR why the other party felt they couldn't approach you directly', especially when you make it clear that you're trying to find out if there's something you need to work on to make yourself more approachable. Obviously it's very likely that things would have been far less painful for everyone involved if the OP *had* been approached directly about this.

Answer (score 7):

It's difficult to say why your coworker went to HR. Perhaps he's shy, or didn't know how to talk to you, or perhaps there's some other reason. We don't know.

The problem now is things are a bit awkward between you and him. You thought all was fine and well and it seems like they're not. So the best way to deal with this is to break the ice with him directly. There is no need to make a big deal about it. Just next time you see him around the office, behave like everything is exactly the same, be friendly and smile and say something like "I didn't realize that my hand lotion was a problem! I've changed it now and I hope this one is better. You're welcome to let me know if there's anything else bothering you!"

And then after that, put it behind you and go on as if everything is the same. It's in the past now.

If you don't know who it is that complained, you can say the same thing to your teammates all together, just make a light-hearted remark like above, be friendly and then move on an put it behind you.